# How to get attribute value from XML/MPD file?

Tags: jquery, xml, mpeg-dash, mpd

I'm trying to get to values from attributes on a MPD file, which is an XML file, in other to pass it to another function. No luck until now. I'll appreciate any help.

Values I'm looking on `<ContentProtection>`: `default_KID`

XML File:

```
<ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc" cenc:default_KID="63F31554-C8A7-93D7-B131-7C01612D8D91"/>
<ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:5E629AF5-38DA-4063-8977-97FFBD9902D4" value="Marlin">
    <cenc:pssh>AAAAKHBzc2gAAAAAXmKa9TjaQGOJd5f/vZkC1AAAAAgAAAAIbWFybA==</cenc:pssh>
    <mas:MarlinContentIds>
        <mas:MarlinContentId>urn:marlin:kid:42eb30ca4481312db87a91119d6f0b28</mas:MarlinContentId>
    </mas:MarlinContentIds>
</ContentProtection>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `default_KID` in the XML part you mentioned, but you can use the Marlin KID. The [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) can be used to parse the XML string:

```
var xml = '<ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:5E629AF5-38DA-4063-8977-97FFBD9902D4" value="Marlin"><cenc:pssh>AAAAKHBzc2gAAAAAXmKa9TjaQGOJd5f/vZkC1AAAAAgAAAAIbWFybA==</cenc:pssh><mas:MarlinContentIds><mas:MarlinContentId>urn:marlin:kid:42eb30ca4481312db87a91119d6f0b28</mas:MarlinContentId></mas:MarlinContentIds></ContentProtection>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var parsedXml = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
parsedXml.getElementsByTagName('MarlinContentId')[0].textContent
```

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't notice it was hidden.